# Maven Plugin log4j logging with slf4j does not log in file

Tags: maven, logging, plugins, log4j, slf4j

I have an issue with logging in a maven plugin for my applicaton. The maven plugin uses log4j with slf4j as facade, and I have configured (in the plugin) a special file logger for outputs. 
When I run my plugin application (local, not as a plugin), the output is written to the file as intended.
However, when I use the maven plugin in another project and build it with `mvn clean install`, the output is only on the console. It seems not to be a problem of configuration as I do find my logger and (file-)appender.

My assumption is that maven absorbs the slf4j output to display it on its own console. Can anybody confirm or determine this respective tell me how to fix it? I appreciate any help.

Comment: what is the logging mechanism you are using. you are only referring to the logging of the maven plugin.

Comment: I'm using log4j and slf4j for both my plugin and my project where I want to use my plugin in.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your actual POM file.  However, there are a few potential problems that I know about.This dependency is required because the

The maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3 has a dependency on maven-core:2.2.1, which has direct or indirect dependencies on sl4j-nop:1.5.3 and slf4j-jdk14:1.5.6.  I introduced a dependency on maven-core:3.3.9, which didn't have this problem.  The artifact maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3 also has a dependency on log4j:log4j.  I placed an exclusion on the dependency for maven-javadoc-plugin so that it didn't include log4j:log4j.

See https://bradleyaross.wordpress.com/2016/05/05/java-logging-frameworks/ and the referenced GitHub libraries, especially the pom.xml files for the parent module and tutorials-common.